# Winamp Library Not Displaying Crossover

Tags: macos, compatibility, winamp, crossover

I'm having issues with getting the winamp library displaying in crossover in both `OSX Mavericks` and `Ubuntu 13.10`. I'm using version 13 in `crossover`.

I have installed `directx` and then winamp 6.66.

[image]

Comment: have you also tried it on wine?

Comment: I have in ubuntu, the same problem sadly. I hadn't even thought to look if wine was available on osx. Always been an ubuntu man :)

Comment: by the way there is also a native mac Version of Winamp https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40721/winamp no garantie on anything - havn't tested it on my own but maybe it helps you

Comment: Yep, installed it. Sadly its nothing like the windows version. But thanks for looking. There are so many features that Winamp offers over  any other player I have found. But its the sorting the album views by year thats really killing me currently.

Comment: don't you like itunes ? it is able to sort the albums on every possible way i can think of and two great plus iphone/ipad/ipod sync and smart playlists and its free bundled within os x.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't order by release date in itunes? If you can and it supports flac then I'm in baby :)

Comment: ok point against itunes no flac as far as i know - will try it out as soon as i am @home

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13457/discussion-between-konqui-and-jamie-hutber)